# CSS files loaded in Layout does not apply to Partial Views

Tags: asp.net, css, razor, partial-views

I am linking a generic css file from my _ReportLayout file for my whole project, but for some reason it does not apply to my partial views! The css styles load just fine for the rendered body, but not the partial views inside it. (Examples given in the context of a report/journal writing system.)

_ReportLayout:

```
  <head>
     ...
     <link href="~/Content/Report.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
```

Rendered body:

```
@model JournalSystem.Models.Report

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Write Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Report.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Journal/RapportSections/Title_Banner.cshtml", Model)

<h2>More report entries...</h2>
```

The partial view:

```
@model JournalSystem.Models.Report

<header>
    <h1 class="title">
        @Html.DisplayFor(r => r.SomeEntry.Name)
    </h1>

    <img class="logo" src="~/Images/Company_logo.png"/>
</header>
```

What really confuses me is that styles written written directly with scripts tags in the _ReportLayout file *will* apply to the partial views, it just won't work with external style sheets.

Can someone please help me on this one? I don't want to write the entire css inside script tags. :-)

**Solved, see comments:**

Reloading the entire project in Visual Studio seemed to be the solution - the CSS files edited in VS were not the ones uploaded to the page. Tips, update CSS files in the browser with CRTL+R (the files get cached). Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the rendered source code to see if the css file is there?  Have you checked with a browser dev tool to see if the css file has downloaded?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't think of using the F12 tool! It seems like only parts of the CSS files are actually loaded, although they are all in the same file. Could it be that somehow only styles 'used' are loaded, and that the tags and classes inside the partial view is invisible in this sense?

Comment: No it would not just load the styles 'used', the broswer will download the whole file. Sounds like you could have a syntax error in your css file if not all of it has loaded.  You can validate your css file here http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I ran the validator, and it did not find any errors. On the other hand, it showed all the code that was not loaded into the F12 tool. This made me believe that the files I changed in Visual Studio was not the ones loaded to runtime. To verify this I reloaded the project from scratch, which solved the issue. Thank you for your feedback, I would not have realised this without it!